# an integral on the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose $S^n$ is the unit sphere and $f,g$ are two smooth functions on $S^n$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ and $g(-x)=-g(x)$ for all $x\in S^n.$
Why is it true that

$$\int_{S^n}f(x)g(x)dx=0?$$

The antipodal map $A: S^n\to S^n, x\mapsto -x$ has Jacobian $(-1)^{n+1}.$ So I can see why it is zero only for $n$ odd.

Comment: $g(x)=-g(x)?$$\,\,$

Comment: Won't work! Because both f and g are odd, and their product is not odd anymore.

Comment: $h=fg$ is an odd function when $f$ is even and $g$ is odd. Just break the sphere into two hemispheres and use symmetry. You're misleading yourself when you write $dx$. This is the usual $dV$ (not as a differential form), and so you take the absolute value of the jacobian determinant here.

Comment: @Behnam: Read more carefully. $f$ is even.

Comment: f=g case refutes your claim!

Comment: it was a typo $g(-x)=-g(x).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the integration into addition of integral on two hemispheres. On one hemisphere, we have the same function values over similar surface areas, except for a minus sign in the values. This proves that the two hemispheres give opposite sign integrals, which cancel out to zero.

Getting into details, any kind of parameterization you use on one hemisphere, apply the same to the other one. So, domains and Jacobians of the parameterizations will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If $h$ is continuous on $S,$ then $\int_Sh(x)\, dx = \int_Sh(-x)\, dx.$ It follows that if $h(-x)=-h(x),$ then $\int_S h(x)\,dx = 0.$ Apply this to $h(x)= f(x)g(x).$